# Fixing a Core Data mess up (released to app store before versioning)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, core-data

I was (and still am) new to core data when I released a version (lets call it version 1.1) of my app to the app store that had a few added attributes and did not version core data.

I then learned about versioning and versioned core data using these steps:

- remove the attributes that were added before I released the last version
- create a new version
- Magical Record handled the rest
- released a new version (version 1.2) to the app store

Ok too make this a little bit easier to follow, here are the types of users I'm talking about:

Groups:

- A = downloaded version 1.1 and updated to 1.2
- B = had version 1.0 (before core data change) and updated to 1.1 (or didn't) then 1.2

Now Group B is working fine but group A is experiencing crashes. Rather than telling them all to re-download the app, I'd like to be able to fix this issue once and for all.

I haven't found anything online about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Unless I am mistaken your only option is to write some of your own custom code that checks the version of the database on startup and migrates it to v1.2.  It would appear that your v1.2 has an upgrade path from v1.0 but does not have an upgrade path from v1.1.  So you need to include in V1.3 the V1.2 model and some additional code to check if the database version is v1.1 and then have custom code to copy the data to the v1.2 database.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an article or something that can elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Mmm, nope but it's not too hard.  Code for copying the data across should be a matter of looping through objects from the old database and creating them in the new one and recreating the relationships.  Checking the version of the Core Data file should also be possible.  I do something along those lines in the CoreDataStackManager here http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/.  Have a look at the code and see if that provides a start point.